# Nesting of StreamReader and StreamWriter inside a while loop in C#

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I am doing a code where I have a text file which consist of lets say 10000+ lines of unique keys(each key in a new line). I need to insert the keys into a table along with the ProductID and ProductFeatures provided by me.

I have achieved this by using the following code which checks for the already existing key inside the table and reduces redundancy of the keys(no key will be featured twice inside the table).

```
public void reader(string productid,string productfeature)
{
    con.Open();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("keys.txt")))
    {
        while(sr.Peek() >=0)
        {
            string str = sr.ReadLine();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(newkey) from serialkey where newkey ='"+str.ToString()+"'", con);
            int keyvalue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (keyvalue == 0)
            {
                com = new SqlCommand("insert into SerialKey (productid,productfeatures,newkey) values ('" + productid.ToString() + "','" + productfeature.ToString() + "','" + key + "')", con);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

This code works absolutely fine for me, but however i have decided to make a few modifications in the process.

1. As soon as the key is inserted into the table the key(line) should be deleted from the text file.

For this I guess I have to use StreamWriter/Textwriter inside the same while loop so I tried using this code.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("keys.txt")))
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        string str = sr.ReadLine();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(newkey) from serialkey where newkey ='" + str.ToString() + "'", con);
        int keyvalue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (keyvalue == 0)
        {
            string line = null;
            sr.Close();
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("keys.txt"), true);
            if (insert(productid, productfeature, str))
            {
                if (str != null)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }                    
        }
    }
}
```

I think I have used the correct logic for deleting the line which has been inserted.
If I keep the line of code

```
sr.Close();
```

I get the following error

> "Cannot read from a closed TextReader."

If I remove the line

```
sr.Close();
```

I get the error

> "The process cannot access the file 'myfolderpath\keys.txt' because it
>   is being used by another process."

Is there I can use the nesting of StreamReader and StreamWriter inside a whileloop. In the end I have to delete the line which has just been inserted into the table.

Thanks in advance,

Viknesh

Comment: Why do you need to "remove" the line in a loop, wouldn't it be more efficient and less prone to errors if you'd simply rewrite the file at the end according to the inserted keys? Btw, you should dispose the connection in the method by use of `using`-statement, all the most if this is ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes down to writing to the file as you read it.

Below a certain max-possible filesize, the simplest way to do this is to read the whole thing into memory first, so you've a list of lines to work with. Just add lines that will be kept to a list, and write them after you closed the reader.

After a certain size, that'll use too much memory, but you can write to a different file, and then copy it over the old file afterwards.

I'd give examples, but other problems with the code mean I can't quite figure out what you are doing (`line` is always null, but is being written, `str` is never null but is checked in case it is).

Comment: Here im just trying to write a null value to the particular place inside the text file where the keys existed. Str is nothing but the key value stored inside a string.

Comment: Writing `null` does nothing to a textwriter does nothing. I don't see how `str` ceases to be the value from `ReadLine()`, which is not null. `line` however is always null, so you open the stream to append to (add stuff at the end) and then do nothing with it. Alternatively if you'd opened it as not appending, you would have a zero-byte file at the end.

Comment: Tats what i want to do. It doesnt bother me if the keys.txt file doesnt have any thing inside it. Even if its Zero-bytes thats ok with me. In other words i can say that i just want to replace the line containing my key by a null value.

Answer (score 0):

I still couldnt sort the method to obtain the content from the keys.txt file then insert key to my table and then delete the line(in which the key exists) from the keys.txt file. 
The deletion of a key from the txt file should take place as soon as the particular key is inserted inside the table, But somehow i have sorted another way round but i dont think its efficient enough.

Here i obtain all the keys and store them in an array then insert them using foreach loop after that clear the contents of the txt file.

But still i prefer the former method due to its performance issues. Yet anyone can try this chunk of code.

The time delay for obtaining 3000 lines of keys from the file keys.txt and then inserting them inside the table take me around 8seconds.

Im still quoting out the source code in the following lines

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("keys.txt")))
    {

        string keys = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] allkeys = Regex.Split(keys, "\r\n");
        foreach (string values in allkeys)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(newkey) from serialkey where newkey ='" + values.ToString() + "'", con);
            int keyvalue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            if (keyvalue == 0)
            {
                com = new SqlCommand("insert into SerialKey (productid,productfeatures,newkey) values ('" + productid.ToString() + "','" + productfeature.ToString() + "','" + key + "')", con);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
        sr.Close();
        File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("keys.txt"), string.Empty);
}
```

Hope this chunk of code helps someone with same sort of problem. This is just an alternate way for me not the solution to my query.